# May a temporary object be dereferenced and passed further in another function?

Tags: c++

Basically I have two related questions. Let's assume, there is a function to create a shared pointer, for example:
`std::shared_ptr<int> create_ptr(int val)`

And there is a function which accepts by reference, for example:
`void print(int& val)`

I want to create a shared pointer and pass it directly to the function as follows:
`print(*create_ptr(123))`

Operator*() should return me a reference, but it will be the reference to the temporary object.

Could you tell me, if this is still safe to do so and completely normal in terms of the C++ rules?

I am no sure, but I assume, it is normal, because the object is allocated and not deleted, until the function is finished. So the shared pointer is temporary, but the object is allocated really.

If this is the case, then it can explain, why the following code is compiled well:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> create_ptr(int val)
{
    return std::make_shared<int>(val);
}

void print(int& val)
{
    std::cout << "*** Print value: " << val << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print(*create_ptr(123)); // Why does it work?
}
```

When I first wrote the code, I expected a compile error, because the passed object is temporary, and now I am still confused, why should this work? How would you explain it

Thank you!

The code was tested with GCC-10, and it was compiled well and worked as expected.

Comment: *I expected a compile error*, *Why does it work?* The expectation is wrong. [`*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*) returns `int&`, `int& val`  is bound successfully, there is no any compiler error.

Comment: *"I expected a compile error"* Lifetime issue is rarely detected at compile time... and at runtime, it invokes UB so anything can happens... But fortunately, you are ok :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected a compile error, because the passed object is temporary, and now I am still confused, why should this work?

It compiles because the indirection operator overload of the shared pointer class is not lvalue ref qualified, so it's valid to call it on rvalues such as the temporary.

> I assume, it is normal, because the object is allocated and not deleted, until the function is finished.

Your assumption is correct. It doesn't explain why the program compiles, but it explains why the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, and the answer is closer to what I was asking. My assumption about allocation is based on the fact: if the objects is allocated, it has an address and can be referenced. In this regard, this is valid: int& ref = *create_ptr(123).

Answer (score 3):

The lifetime of the ptr will last for the evaluation of the entire expression which includes the call to `print`.

from the [specs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime):

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
> full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were
> created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are
> destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true
> even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, it makes sense, but it does not explain exactly, why the print() function works fine with the temporary shared_ptr, when it does not work with some other temporaries, e.g. this gives the common error: print(1).